# Number of unique Accounts per custom field report

Tags: custom-reports, joined-reports

I have a text field `myTextField__c` custom field on Account object and i want to create a Lightning report "Unique myTextFields" where i want to have a number (a dashboard gauge) of customers that have a value in myTextField__c that is unique between all Accounts... For example, i have 5 accounts

```
1) has myTextField__c value "george"
2) has myTextField__c value "mattyas"
3) has myTextField__c value "george" 
4) has myTextField__c value "johnson" 
5) has myTextField__c value "robben"
```

I want to display only the 3 Accounts, that are having unique value on this field. How can i do this ? I tried using summary formulas but unfortunately i could not find solution. Any ideas?